# display image based on select box choice

Tags: jquery

I am doing an advertising form , with preview ad below.

So as user types their advert, the preview updates as they go.
One of the selections is dropdown box, where they can choose their service type..

I have a master div, for the preview. And I want to add a image in one corner of that div, based on the selection choice from the advert form...

So in drop down select, we have:

```
<select style="width: 220px; display: none;" id="speedB" name="category">
    <option value=""<?if ($category == ""){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Please Select</option>
    <option value="1"<?if ($category == "1"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Pest Inspectors</option>
    <option value="3"<?if ($category == "3"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Building Inspectors</option>
    <option value="2"<?if ($category == "2"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Removalists</option>
    <option value="5"<?if ($category == "5"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Conveyancing</option>
    <option value="4"<?if ($category == "4"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Pool Inspectors</option>
</select>
```

And in the preview div I have:

```
<div class="dirResult">
<div class="showImage"></div>
</div>
```

So the div "showImage" is what I want to initiate based on the choice user has selected in the select dropdown in the form.

so:
if value="1" then show pest.png
if value="2" then show build.png
so on and so forth.

Is there a simple way to do this ?
I suppose showImage div must be pre-set to display:none

But after that I am stumped.

UPDATE

Based on ingenu's answer below.

I am thinking perhaps add different div classes instead of individual pngs, that way I can control css etc.

So something like :

```
$('#speedB').change(function() {
                      var myimages = {
                        '': '.nothing',
                        '1': '.pest',
                        '2': '.build'
                      }
                      var selectedImage = myimages[$(this).val()];
                      $('#topright').html('not sure what to put here');});
```

Then in css have:

```
.pest {
background: url("pest.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 70px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a prototype: (untested)

```
$('#speedB').change(function() {
  var myimages = {
    '': 'default.png',
    '1': 'pest.png',
    '2': 'build.png'
  }
  var selectedImage = myimages[$(this).val()];
  $('.showImage').html('<img src="'+selectedImage+'" alt="" />');
});
```

Edit: Inserting containers instead of images:

```
$('#speedB').change(function() {
  var myclasses = {
    '': 'default',
    '1': 'pest',
    '2': 'build'
  }
  var selectedClass = myclasses[$(this).val()];
  $('.showImage').html('<div class="'+selectedClass+'"></div>');
});
```

Comment: would it make more sense to make showImage an ID and var myimages separate image classes, instead of the actual images, I like this approach

Comment: Have updated question based on your reply, could you assist please

Comment: @422 I updated the answer. Basically, you can inject any code you want on the select change. The general approach is to keep a hash/dictionary that maps values from the option to some code you want to inject in the result.

Comment: lol yep figured it too.. chosen cheers mate ( I added on another question ) sorry will vote now

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#speedB').change(function(){
        $('.showImage').html('<img src="$(this).val();" />');
    });
});
```

The following code will know when the ID element of "speedB" is changed and will replace the HTML contents of the class "showImage" with an image and the source of that image will be pulled from the value of the selected item on the dropdown. So for Pest Inspectors, change the value of that option to "pest.png".

Make sure you include the jQuery library before the script above, too. You can find the code at www.jquery.com.

Comment: You're forgetting to concatenate the selected value.

Comment: Have updated question, perhaps this is a sleeker solution, not sure how to invoke the css tho